# order by added column not working in CLOUDERA

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, cloudera

I've created a table in CLOUDERA and then added a column to it with:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMNS (`new_col` VARCHAR(40));
```

then i'm trying to select with order by:

```
select col1,col2,new_col from table1 order by 1,2,3
```

however this is fails.

it is working without order by clause.
it is also working  without selecting the new_col in select statement.

any ideas what causing the failure?

edit:
i think it happens because new column contain nulls. how can i overcome this issue?

Comment: What is you hive version?

Comment: hive 1.1.0-cdh5.11.0